# How to play mp3 audio in an application for firefox os?

Tags: audio, mp3, firefox-os

I tried with several players but only supports the format. Ogg player or there any way to play a. Mp3 in firefox os. I also used to open the audio player of Firefox with the default OS file. Mp3

Comment: Are you trying to play mp3 on your own app or on the Music app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Firefox OS Simulator does not support mp3 playback. 
but the Firefox OS device support it.